# Как загрузить конфиг в библиотеку Python?

Tags: python, pypi

Доброй ночи.
Есть вот такая библиотека:

```
lib/
│
├── lib/
│     ├── __init__.py
│     ├── main.py
│     └── config.py
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
└── setup.cpy
```

После загрузки и установки библиотеки, пытаюсь импортировать библиотеку:

```py
import lib
```

И мне выходит такая ошибка:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

Структура setup.py файла:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

def readme():
  with open('README.md', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    return f.read()

setup(
  name='lib',
  version='1.0.7',
  author='author',
  author_email='author@gmail.com',
  description='some desc',
  long_description=readme(),
  long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
  url='url',
  packages=find_packages(),
  classifiers=[
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
    'Operating System :: OS Independent'
  ],
  keywords='python',
  project_urls={
    'Documentation': 'docs'
  },
  python_requires='>=3.7'
)
```

Вот код init.py файла:

```py
import main
import config
```

Что делать - незнаю. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете попробовать добавить файл `config.py` в список экспортируемых модулей, которые будут доступны после установки библиотеки.

1. В структуру `setup.py` файла добавьте `package_data` аргумент, следующим образом:

```python
...

setup(
  ...
  packages=find_packages(),
  package_data={
    'lib': ['config.py']
  },
  classifiers=[
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
    'Operating System :: OS Independent'
  ],
  ...
)
```

2. Так же необходимо добавить префикс `lib` в `init.py` файл:

```python
import lib.main
import lib.config
```

После переустановки пакета, модуль `config` должен стать доступным для импорта из `lib`

Comment: Так, теперь он жалуется на файл main.py, попробую вместо import config сделать import lib.config (до этого жаловался на init.py)

Comment: Да, все работает, спасибо!

Comment: Чудесно, успехов Вам в Ваших проектах :)